# sahi not showing chrome browser option on sahi dashboard

Tags: operating-system, windows-xp, sahi

[image]

Sahi not showing chrome browser option on sahi dashboard. My OS is XP. Any one tell me what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this post http://sahitesting.com/sahi/understanding-browser-configuration-in-sahi-pro/
Here I have provided the solution for same.

Video explaining how to configure browsers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-4ciPcltZw

Comment: The link to the post is broken.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "browser_types.xml" under the folder "\sahi_pro\userdata\config"
2. Add the following content on browser_types.xml and save the file:

   chrome
           Chrome
           chrome.png
           $LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
           --user-data-dir=$userDir\browser\chrome\profiles\sahi$threadNo --proxy-server=localhost:9999 --disable-popup-blocking --always-authorize-plugins
           chrome.exe 
           5
3. Now open Sahi Dashborad

Comment: Check this to understand how browser configuration works in Sahi. http://sahitesting.com/sahi/understanding-browser-configuration-in-sahi-pro/

Answer (score 0):

What I do mostly is right click on the chrome icon on desktop, copy the path in the target textbox

[image]

and paste in the  node in browser.xml under chrome's node.